# Unexpected behaviour of Python's os.path.relpath

Tags: python, os.path

I am having trouble using network addresses. Tried in Python3.6 with Windows. Invoking

```
os.path.relpath(r"\\ZEYCUS\first\second\file.txt", start=r"\\ZEYCUS\first")
```

I get `'second\\file.txt'`, as I would expect. But with

```
os.path.relpath(r"\\ZEYCUS\first\second\file.txt", start=r"\\ZEYCUS")
```

I get an error message: `ValueError: path is on mount '\\\\ZEYCUS\\first', start on mount 'C:'`.

What is going on? Where did the `C:` bit come from? How should I use `relpath` to obtain `'first\\second\\file.txt'`?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/17506586/1836483

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `r'\\ZEYCUS'` isn't actually an OS path. It is a network host specifier. Windows uses drive letters, inherited from DOS, between which there are no relative paths; relative paths only function within a drive. `r"\\ZEYCUS\first"` is a network volume, which operates like a drive. In effect that whole part turns into an implicit drive letter. `C:` would most likely be your system drive, possibly the current drive of the Python process. If you try just `dir \\zeycus` in Cmd you'll find that's an invalid volume syntax (in a rather unhelpful message) even though the same specifier in Explorer produces a volume listing.

Comment: @Vernier thanks, I tried and indeed it works as you say, I'm afraid my lack of network knowledge is showing here.